# Return multiple arrays of flat data while running Map on object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to extract multiple flat arrays of values from an object array.

I'm able to extract the values needed using ES6 Map, but I'd like to separate these values into individual arrays without having to loop multiple times.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
    let list = [
        {
            "name": "namee 1",
            "type": "type 1",
            "deal_type": "dealtype1"
        },
        {
            "name": "namee 2",
            "type": "type 2",
            "deal_type": "dealtype2"
        },
        {
            "name": "namee 3",
            "type": "type 3",
            "deal_type": "dealtype3"
        },
        {
            "name": "namee 1",
            "type": "type 1",
            "deal_type": "dealtype1"
        }
    ]

  const summary = test.map(item => ({ deal_type: item.deal_type, type: item.type}));
```

The desired outcome would be the following output from one .Map loop:

```
type = ["type 1", "type 2", "type 3"] 
deal_type = ["dealtype1", "dealtype2", "dealtype3"]
```

Comment: So do you want to be able to access the items with 
```summary.type
```
and
```summary.deal_type
``` ?

Comment: Do you need to get 2 arrays from the original array?

Comment: Why `map` and not `reduce`? You can achieve it with `const {type, deal_type} = list.reduce(..., { type: [], deal_type: [] });`.

Comment: Yes I need two separate arrays from one original array without having to loop more than once.

Comment: @DreamBold `...` isn't a magic operator. You have to replace it with actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with `reduce` instead of `map` using an array:

```js
let list = [{"name": "namee 1","type": "type 1","deal_type": "dealtype1"},{"name": "namee 2","type": "type 2","deal_type": "dealtype2"},{"name": "namee 3","type": "type 3","deal_type": "dealtype3"},{"name": "namee 1","type": "type 1","deal_type": "dealtype1"}];

const [type, deal_type] = list.reduce((acc, el) => (
  acc[0].push(el.type),
  acc[1].push(el.deal_type),
  acc
), [[], []]);
console.log(type);
console.log(deal_type);
```

or more verbose using an object

```js
let list = [{"name": "namee 1","type": "type 1","deal_type": "dealtype1"},{"name": "namee 2","type": "type 2","deal_type": "dealtype2"},{"name": "namee 3","type": "type 3","deal_type": "dealtype3"},{"name": "namee 1","type": "type 1","deal_type": "dealtype1"}];

const { type, deal_type } = list.reduce((acc, el) => (
  acc.type.push(el.type),
  acc.deal_type.push(el.deal_type),
  acc
), { type: [], deal_type: [] });
console.log(type);
console.log(deal_type);
```

or if you want to remove duplicates:

```js
let list = [{"name": "namee 1","type": "type 1","deal_type": "dealtype1"},{"name": "namee 2","type": "type 2","deal_type": "dealtype2"},{"name": "namee 3","type": "type 3","deal_type": "dealtype3"},{"name": "namee 1","type": "type 1","deal_type": "dealtype1"}];

const [type, deal_type] = list.reduce((acc, el) => (
  acc[0].add(el.type),
  acc[1].add(el.deal_type),
  acc
), [new Set(), new Set()]).map(el => [...el]);
console.log(type);
console.log(deal_type);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was hoping to accomplish. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try either of these:
With `map` function:

```
const types = list.map((item) => item.type); 
const deal_type = list.map((item) => item.deal_type);
```

Or with `forEach`:

```
const types = [], deal_type = [];  
list.forEach((item) => {   
types.push(item.type);   
deal_type.push(item.deal_type); 
});
```

Or with `reduce`:

```
const { type, deal_type } = list.reduce(
  (a, c) => {
    a.type = [...a.type, c.type];
    a.deal_type = [...a.deal_type, c.deal_type];
    return a;
  },
  { type: [], deal_type: [] }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Foreach may be the solution- though I'm also wondering, is it possible to have two separate returns from the map function? Ideally something like `types, deal_types = list.map((item) => item.type, item.deal_type)` though this example does not work.

Comment: Thank you this is also very insightful! Appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
const type = list.map((item) => item.type);  
const deal_type = list.map((item) => item.deal_type);
```

or

```
const type = [];
const deal_type = [];

list.foreach((item) => {
     type.push(item.type);
     deal_type.push(item.deal_type);
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply- though I am looking for a solution that only uses one loop

Comment: I typed on answer for you . look  up again answer